# Can mirroring at import time be controlled on a group by group basis?

Tags: gitlab

I have multiple groups under which I am importing applications from a separate bitbucket/stash. When I import, there is a checkbox for mirroring. When I check the checkbox, I expect mirroring to take place.

For one of the groups I am importing applications to, for every application I import, mirroring is successful on import.

For any other group, for every application, mirroring on import fails to happen. I end up having to manually set mirroring by going to settings, repository, mirroring. This is successful, however having to manually add mirroring in this manner almost doubles my import time.

Is there a setting I missed on the groups which do not mirror properly on import?

There is no error message produced. Mirroring simply is not established even though the box for mirroring has been checked. I never have this problem with the other group. All applications are being imported from the same bitbucket/stash.

If I import the same application to both groups, the always-successful group will mirror on import and any other will fail to mirror on import. I feel this must be related to a setting on the group, which is preventing mirroring at import time.

Is there a setting that controls (enables/disables) mirroring at import time for a group, where is it, and how do I change it?